# Can you run sudo -c and retain privileges?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, su

Can you run `su root -c "$some_command"`, and remain signed in as the `root` user, instead of dropping privileges immediately after executing the command (i.e. back out to the regular user)?

In other words: I want to execute a command as `root`, and retain `su` privileges until `exit`.

For instance, currently, I simply:
 1. Execute `su`.
 2. Type the `root` password when prompted with `Password:`.
 3. Execute `$some_command` (*or for **example**:* `source ./.bashrc`).
 4. Retain elevated privileges, and do a few other things until...
 5. `exit`.

Whereas if I use `-c`, it just runs that first command and bails, not giving me any time to do the other things I need to do. If not, it's not the end of the world, there are other ways to deal with it, but it would be nice to be able to do it this way is all.

---

Note: Naturally, I thought `su root -l -c "$some_command"` was the solution, but:
a. It changes to the `/root` directory (which isn't really a problem).
b. When `-l` is issued with `-c`, it executes the first command and just exits.

Answer (score 3):

You can start another shell:

```
su root -c "${some_command}; bash"
```

replacing `bash` with your favourite shell if necessary.

Comment: I'll give it a bash. Why the braces?

Comment: Force of habit around long variable names, I find it makes the code easier to read and avoids problems with variable name delimitation.